# Prevent HTML form from POSTing if it doesn't pass client side validation

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I have this very simple HTML form, when I submit, it does POST to /productos and runs a JS script that validates the form, if its not correct, it displays an error, all good.

But one thing I want to do is to "cancel" the POST if the form doesn't pass that validation, is there any way to do it?

I have thought about making the POST from the javascript function instead of from the form itself, but I have no idea how to do that

html:

```html
<form name="registro" action="/productos" method='post' onsubmit="return validacion()">
<div>titulo</div>
<input type="text", name="titulo"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

js validation:

```
function validacion(){
    var titulo=document.registro.titulo.value;
    if (titulo == ""){
        alert("error, titulo cant be empty")

    } else if (titulo.length > 100){
        alert("error, titulo cant be more than 100 characters long")
    }
```

Comment: Also don't assume they still can't post the form any dev can still submit your form and bypass any js validation so make sure you still do server side validation and error reporting.

Comment: @Danny I have that, its just that i got asked to do that so the server doesnt have to validate every single form that submits. So now even if they try to bypass that it wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make validacion() return true or false

```
function validacion(){
    var titulo=document.registro.titulo.value;
    if (titulo == ""){
        alert("error, titulo cant be empty")
        return false;

    } else if (titulo.length > 100){
        alert("error, titulo cant be more than 100 characters long")
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <form name="registro" action="/productos" method="post">
 <div>titulo</div>
 <input type="text", name="titulo" required="required" />
 <input type="submit">
 </form> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

no need for javascript run abounts are needed.

Its easier to use standard html5 with xhtml compatibility method, like this, for form validation:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <form name="registro" action="/productos" method="post">
 <div>titulo</div>
 <input type="text", name="titulo" required="required" />
 <input type="submit">
 </form> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: im just adding layers of "security" so an user that decides to edit the html or the js cant submit a non valid form, i also have another layer in the server, thanks

Comment: On the subject of security, it doesn't matter if the client is using a modern web browser (via webtools => inspect element). because they can delete the require attribute as well as disable the on submit and run it. No client side filtering, nor validation can ever be effective beyond, just being a convenience factor, so they accidentally don't submit an empty post data.

Comment: thats why i said i have server validation anyways... im just doing this so nobody from normal user to someone that actively tries to send a non valid form cant do it

Comment: always use:  htmlentities($_POST['str'], ENT_QUOTES, $encoding="UTF-8"); on your next page

Comment: who says they would even use the web page in the first place, because they can send code just using the wget command on a terminal window or dos prompt

Comment: Never rely on client side filtering for your server security.

Comment: I have server security i just want normal people not to make the server work for every submit that happens, its simple

Comment: the "required" attribute is on the client side and its compiled as part of the web browser, so there is no reason to make a javascript code because there is one there already in memory via the web browser.

Comment: And it does not send anything to the server until that code is satisfied. its the better method because javascript is optional coding, and can be disabled with plugins like NoScript.